# Script for displaying respective WORK days, TRAVEL days and LEAVE days for a particular month

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, pivot

This is how the available data (Table Name: tblAttendanceD ) is

```
    EmployeeNo     | Type   | StartDate  | EndDate

    M1975012200006 | TRAVEL | 06/03/2013 | 06/03/2013 
    M1975040500009 | TRAVEL | 06/17/2013 | 06/17/2013 

    M1975012200006 | WORK   | 06/04/2013 | 07/15/2013 
    M1975040500009 | WORK   | 06/18/2013 | 09/01/2013 

    M1975012200006 | LEAVE  | 07/17/2013 | 09/01/2013 
    M1975040500009 | LEAVE  | 09/03/2013 | 10/15/2013 


    --declare temporary table to store example data
    DECLARE @tblAttendanceD TABLE (EmployeeName VARCHAR(30), 
    EmployeeNo VARCHAR(30),         
    [AttendanceType VARCHAR(30), Start_Date DATETIME, End_Date DATETIME)

    --insert data into temporary table
    INSERT INTO @tblAttendanceD (EmployeeName, EmployeeNo, [Type] , StartDate, EndDate)
    SELECT 'Dumitru', 'M1975012200006', 'TRAVEL', '06/03/2013', '06/03/2013'
    UNION ALL SELECT 'Mottaghi', 'M1975040500009', 'TRAVEL', '06/17/2013', 
    '06/17/2013' 
    UNION ALL SELECT 'Alvarado', 'M1986092400012', 'TRAVEL', '06/03/2013', 
    '06/03/2013' 
    UNION ALL SELECT 'Mottaghi', 'M1975040500009', 'WORK', '06/18/2013', '09/01/2013' 
    UNION ALL SELECT 'Alvarado', 'M1986092400012', 'WORK', '06/04/2013', '07/15/2013' 
    UNION ALL SELECT 'Mottaghi', 'M1975040500009', 'LEAVE', '09/03/2013', '10/15/2013' 
    UNION ALL SELECT 'Alvarado', 'M1986092400012', 'LEAVE', '07/17/2013', '09/01/2013'
```

I want to display all the days of a month column wise.

The expected output is as follows

### **June Month Timeline**

**Employee Numb 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30**
M1975012200006 T W W W W W W W W  W  W  W  W  W  W  L  L  L  L  L  L L L L L L L L L L L L L L L L
Employee Numb2 W W W W W W W W W  W  W  W  W  W  W  W  W  L  L  L  L L....
etc.

- T - represents TRAVEL days;
- W - represents WORK days;
- L - represents LEAVE days;

### UPDATE as on 07/25/13

I was able to fetch records as shown below. For those dates in the table I could fill corresponding 'Type'.

But the 'Type' should be copied to next dates as well based on the start date and end date.

**Employee Numb 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30**
M1975012200006 T W - - - - - - -  -  -  -  -  -  T  L  -  -  -  -  - - - - - - - - - - - -- - - - -
Employee Numb2 - - - - - - - - -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  T  L  -  -  - -....etc.

Here is the script:

```
    DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
    DECLARE @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

    DECLARE @Days TABLE (DateField DATETIME)
    DECLARE @CurrentDate DATETIME
    DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME
    DECLARE @mydate DATETIME

    SET @mydate = GetDate();

    SELECT @CurrentDate = DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(@mydate)-1),@mydate)
    SELECT @EndDate =DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(DATEADD(mm,1,@mydate))),DATEADD(mm,1,@mydate))

    WHILE @CurrentDate <= @EndDate
    BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @Days VALUES(@CurrentDate)
    SET @CurrentDate = DateAdd(d,1,@CurrentDate)
    End

    SELECT @cols = STUFF((SELECT '],[' +
                            CAST(DAY(DateField) As varchar(10))
                          FROM @Days
                          FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                         ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
                            , 1, 1, '');
    --select @cols;

    SELECT @query =

    'SELECT *
    FROM
    (
    SELECT EmployeeNo, AttendanceType, Day([StartDate]) As [Start_Date] FROM @tblAttendanceD WHERE ISNULL(Deleted,0)=0 
    ) AS t
    PIVOT 
    (
      MAX([AttendanceType]
    ) 
      FOR [Start_Date] IN( ' + RIGHT(@cols, LEN(@cols) - 1) + '] )' +
    ' ) AS p ; ';

    print @query;
     execute(@query);
```

Comment: Can you provide table create statements and insert statements for the example data. Your current example does not provide that information.

Comment: @J. Steen - script and table values are provided above. Please let me know if you need any more info

Comment: @ Sebastian Meine - CREATE table script and INSERT script is been added. Please let me know if you need any more info

Answer (score 0):

Let me help you figure out:

First you need to prepare calendar data set for the month of June

Use Pivot separately along with following and for the days of month June:

1. Travel data
2. Work Data
3. Leave Data

The pivot will work well on individual columns
In order to appear These 3 data sets as one use dynamic query and use union all
and also use case statements to appear T- Travel days etc.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I will try the same. But please try to get a sample script if possible.